# stuck on this code saving to database... on laravel 10

Tags: php, laravel, alpine.js

Can anyone help? I made a dynamic (array) text input + checkbox input using Alpine JS, well in the form I checked C, but when I save to the database it was A instead.
Which part is wrong?

here dynamic input using alpine JS

```html
<div class="mt-4 w-full" x-data="handler()">
    <template class=" grid grid-cols-1 gap-6" x-for="(field, index) in fields" :key="index">
         <div class="flex w-full">
              <div class="font-semibold">
                   <x-input-label for="name" :value="__('Choice')" />
                   <input type="text" class="w-12 border-none focus:border-none hover:border-none" name="question_option_id[]"                                                x-bind:value="String.fromCharCode(65 + index)" readonly>
              </div>
              <div class="px-2">
                   <x-input-label for="name" :value="__('Answer')" />
                   <x-text-input x-bind="field.name" type="text" :name="'name[]'" />
              </div>
              <div class="px-2">
                   <div class=" items-center">
                        <x-input-label for="name" :value="__('Correct Answers')" />
                               <label class="relative flex cursor-pointer items-center rounded-full p-3"
                                   for="check" data-ripple-dark="true">
                                   <x-text-input x-bind="field.check[]" type="checkbox"
                                       :name="'check[]'"
                                        value="yes"
                                        class="before:content[''] peer relative h-5 w-5 cursor-pointer appearance-none rounded-md border border-blue-gray-200 transition-all before:absolute before:top-2/4 before:left-2/4 before:block before:h-12 before:w-12 before:-translate-y-2/4 before:-translate-x-2/4 before:rounded-full before:bg-blue-gray-500 before:opacity-0 before:transition-opacity checked:border-pink-500 checked:bg-pink-500 checked:before:bg-pink-500 hover:before:opacity-10"
                                          id="check" />
                                </label>
                   </div>
              </div>
              <div class="px-2">
                  <x-danger-button type="button" @click="removeField(index)"
                        class="mt-4 ">
                           <i class="fa-regular fa-trash-can text-xl"></i>
                  </x-danger-button>
              </div>
           </div>
       </template>
       <div colspan="4" class="mt-2 text-right">
            <x-sky-button type="button" @click="addNewField()">
                   <i class="fa-solid fa-plus"></i> &nbsp; Add Answer
            </x-sky-button>
       </div>
   </div>
```

Here script for above :

```php
function handler() {
                        return {
                            fields: [],
                            addNewField() {
                                this.fields.push({
                                    name: '',
                                    check: ''
                                });
                            },
                            removeField(index) {
                                this.fields.splice(index, 1);
                            }
                        }
                    }
```

Here the controller :

```php
public function storeQuestion(Request $request)
    {
        $request->validate([
            'intructors' => 'required',
            'question' => 'required',
            'name' => 'required|array', // Validate each answer option
        ]);

        // Create a new exam question
        $examQuestion = new Questions();
        $examQuestion->user_id = $request->intructors;
        $examQuestion->exam_id = $request->exams_id;
        $examQuestion->name = $request->question;

        $examQuestion->save();

        // Save the answer options and their correct statuses
        $options = $request->name;
        $correctAnswers = $request->check;
        foreach ($options as $index => $option) {
            
            //check for checkbox got checked   
            $isCorrect = isset($correctAnswers[$index]) ? 'yes' : 'no';

            // get question id on model question 
            $getQuestion = Questions::where('name', $request->question)->first();

            $examQuestionOption = new QuestionsOption();
            $examQuestionOption->create([
                'user_id' => $request->intructors,
                'question_id' => $getQuestion->id,
                'name' => $option,
                'is_correct_answer' => $isCorrect,
            ]);
        }

        // Redirect or return a response as needed
        return redirect()->route('admin.exams')->with('message', 'Question created successfully');
    }
```

Here example input form :

[input form using dynamic input using alpine JS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lz9av.png)

I have try using AI to check it, but get nothing...

what I want is that checkbox got check based a true answer, but after success saved to database it not the same.

**Here is an example:**

there are 4 answers:   A, B, C, D

the correct answer for the question is C

but after saving to database, it becomes A

Comment: Which part is not working? What have you tried to resolve the problem?

Comment: not yet... checkbox (correct anser) not working..
if im chose C (see on image) and stored to database its change to A

Comment: what i want is the one stored is the correct answer, if im choose C then C on database, not A

Comment: `:name="'check[]'"` - I don't assume alpine is adding any index between those [] (?), so that would definitively be a mistake then. Text input fields _always_ cause an entry in the form submission dataset, but check boxes and radio buttons only do, if they are actually checked. So you won't be able to properly correlate your text input fields with your checkboxes based on the _automatically_ created index.

Comment: <x-text-input x-bind="field.check[]" type="checkbox" name="check[]" value="yes" class="" id="check" />

i have already try using this, but its still same

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The unselected checkboxes are not sent with submit, but we can use an array of hidden fields that will represent the checkboxes states, checkboxes and hidden fields with same index will have the same x-model. To ensure the correct binding I have also added explicit indexes, managing field names in the x-for.

The *check* field of the handler object is now initialized to *false* and I have removed the *value="yes"* in the *<input type="checkbox">*

Also, since splice() will compact indexes, they can't be used as *:key* in the x-for loop, so I have added an additional *key* field in the array of objects, a function *newKey()* to generate a unique fresh key and *lastKey* variable to keep track of the last key used.

I have also removed some *x-bind="...."*

```html
<div class="mt-4 w-full" x-data="handler()">

    <template class=" grid grid-cols-1 gap-6" x-for="(field, index) in fields" :key="field.key">

        <div class="flex w-full">

            <div class="font-semibold">

                <x-input-label :value="__('Choice')" />

                <input type="text"
                       x-bind:name="`question_option_id[${index}]`"
                       class="w-12 border-none focus:border-none hover:border-none"
                       x-bind:value="String.fromCharCode(65 + index)"
                       readonly
                >

            </div>

            <div class="px-2">

                <x-input-label x-bind:for="`name[${index}]`" :value="__('Answer')" />

                <x-text-input type="text"
                              x-model="fields[index].name"
                              x-bind:id="`name[${index}]`"
                              x-bind:name="`name[${index}]`"
                />

            </div>

            <div class="px-2">

                <div class=" items-center">

                    <x-input-label :value="__('Correct Answers')" />

                    <label class="relative flex cursor-pointer items-center rounded-full p-3"
                           data-ripple-dark="true"
                    >
                        <input type="hidden" x-bind:name="`check[${index}]`" x-model="fields[index].check">

                        <x-text-input x-model="fields[index].check"
                                      type="checkbox"
                                      class="before:content[''] peer relative h-5 w-5 cursor-pointer appearance-none rounded-md border border-blue-gray-200 transition-all before:absolute before:top-2/4 before:left-2/4 before:block before:h-12 before:w-12 before:-translate-y-2/4 before:-translate-x-2/4 before:rounded-full before:bg-blue-gray-500 before:opacity-0 before:transition-opacity checked:border-pink-500 checked:bg-pink-500 checked:before:bg-pink-500 hover:before:opacity-10"
                        />

                    </label>

                </div>

            </div>

            <div class="px-2">

                <button type="button" @click="removeField(index)" class="mt-4 ">
                    <i class="fa-regular fa-trash-can text-xl"></i>
                </button>

            </div>

        </div>

    </template>

    <div class="mt-2 text-left">

        <button type="button" @click="addNewField()">

            <i class="fa-solid fa-plus"></i> &nbsp; Add Answer

        </button>

    </div>

    <div x-data></div>
</div>

<script>

    function handler() {

        return {

            lastKey: 0,

            fields: [],

            newKey() {
                return this.lastKey++;
            },

            addNewField() {

                this.fields.push({
                    key: this.newKey(),
                    name: '',
                    check: 'false'
                });
            },

            removeField(index) {

                this.fields.splice(index, 1);
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

In the controller:

```php
$isCorrect = $correctAnswers[$index] == 'true';
```

Comment: it's work,  its just need to change field on table that can accept 1 or 0 , first it got error cause data trucated or something cause on filed "correct_answer" (table) is Enum beetwen yes/no, but now im canging it to integer that can accept 1 or 0. thank you